# How should I code rolling RF remote at the receiver side?

Tags: c, mcu

I ordered a 444MHZ remote and receiver with some buttons on it. The remote has rolling code but when I tested I saw that every button has 8 fixed different possibility and repeat it self.

```
    Button1: (Decimal results)
    
1- 3899572514 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
2- 3899580674 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
3- 3899523362 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
4- 3899531522 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
5- 3899539746 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
6- 3899547906 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
7- 3899556130 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
8- 3899564290 / 32bit PulseLength: 251 microseconds Protocol: 1
```

So, I'm tyring to figure out what is the best method for developing the receiver code.
I tought different ideas but I did not like them at all so I want to take your opinions.

My ideas are:

1- I will record all of these possibilities and use them like "if any one of these" method but this is not secure and I don't want to that.

2- I will record all of these possibilities and expecting other then previous lenght. This is also not suitable because it is not secure either. There are 7 different possibilities and if I have multiple device in a room, remotes goes mixed with this method.

3- If I'm gonna put them order and expect only for the next possibility it could work and it will reduce to mixing with other same device. Thats nice but I can not put them in order because when the device misses a push then it will not work at all. Also there are no ways to know the current lenght when the device rebooted.

P.S: Security is not too much needed. It is gonna a home light system but I want to code the receiver to reach (close as) paired devices for in a case having multiple devices in the room.

Any idea or example will be awesome!

Comment: if you want reliability 1, and if you want "security" 3.  In-between would be a window of accepted values.

Comment: @AllanWind I think I'm missing something because there must be a reason to having rolling code. If I'm gonna accept all of the possibilities then it turns into fixed code. But I believe there is no way to get current code for every button at the begining so the third option is not suitable.

Comment: Rolling code prevents an attacker to record the code an immediately play it back.  In this case they would need to record all codes to figure out which one to send next.  Is this secure, no, not really.

Comment: What modulation is it using? As for rolling code etc, it is mostly for garage door openers.

Comment: @Lundin The remote has MRF212D-2133 chip. It uses ASK modulation and Manchester for encoding and decoding. It is something like RF TV remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching all over the internet finally I've find the data type illusturation.

As you can see the below. The first 16bits is the transmitter ID and it is unique for every remote to prevent mixed signals. the 17-24bits are the button keycode. If it is fixed code then you should only have 1 keycode for each button. If it's rolling code then as you can see mine is incremented by 1. The rest is the control mark and checksum.

So now I know that I should create a sync function for taking the transmitter ID and when I have a transmitter ID I will filter it and grab the keycode information from 17-24bits and call the desired function. Thats it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Standard (Microchip HCS) rolling code transmits 66 bits  which comprise a fixed part, not protected (i.e., not rolling) and a crypted part with changes every time (every new transmission).

Both parts (crypted and not crypted) should transmit always the same code for every button, otherwise there would be no sense in having multiple buttons.

The receiver part should "learn" those codes, and associate them to some function (every different button can do a different thing).

You should consult the documentation of the transmitter, or at least know which protocol it uses, in order to manage the receiving part. But, for a minimum (really minimum) security, you should have the receiver "learn" each button, and subsequently accept only those codes that have been "learned". The next step is to take advantage of the rolling code, if desired - this is much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this remote uses 32bits and this is the not right answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Morphinz, after all you did what I suggested: find the protocol specification. The fact it was "rolling" code was stated by you and, lacking other informations, I did my best to help...